# Calculate $P.V.\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \frac{1}{(2-x) (x^2+4)}$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, analysis

$$(2-x)(x^2+4)=0$$
Roots: $$(2,2i,-2i)$$

$$Res(\frac{1}{(2-x) (x^2+4)},2)=\lim_{x\rightarrow 2} \frac{1}{-(x^2+4)}=-\frac{1}{8}$$

$$Res(\frac{1}{(2-x) (x^2+4)},2i)=\lim_{x\rightarrow 2i} \frac{1}{(2-x)(x+2i)}=\frac{1}{8} \ \frac{1}{i+1} $$

$$P.V.\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \frac{1}{(2-x) (x^2+4)}=\frac{\pi}{4}  i \frac{1}{i+1} - \frac{\pi}{8} i=\frac{\pi}{8}  i (-i+1)-\frac{\pi}{8} i=\frac{\pi}{8}$$

Is it correct?

Thanks!

Comment: P.V. stands for Cauchy Principal Value? Also, what is this $Res$ symbol? Whatever method you're appling, I'm not sure you're allowed to do complex calculus in real analysis. What course is it for?

Comment: I've just noticed that the function you want to integrate over $(- \infty, + \infty)$ is not defined at $x=2$, which means that it doesn't exist, neither does the principal value!

Comment: (-half the residue at the real line+the residue in the upper half plane)*2 pi i

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[8px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}
&\mbox{P.V.}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}{\dd x \over \pars{2 - x}\pars{x^{2} + 4}}
\\[5mm] \stackrel{\mbox{def.}}{=}\,\,\,&\
-\lim_{\epsilon \to 0^{+}}\bracks{%
\int_{-\infty}^{2 - \epsilon}{\dd x \over \pars{x - 2}\pars{x^{2} + 4}} +
\int_{2 + \epsilon}^{\infty}{\dd x \over \pars{x - 2}\pars{x^{2} + 4}}}
\\[5mm] = &\
-\lim_{\epsilon \to 0^{+}}
\bracks{\oint_{\mc{C}}{\dd z \over \pars{z - 2}\pars{z^{2} + 4}} -
\int_{\pi}^{0}{\epsilon\expo{\ic\theta}\ic\,\dd\theta \over \epsilon\expo{\ic\theta}\times 8}}
\\[5mm] = &\
-\lim_{\epsilon \to 0^{+}}\bracks{2\pi\ic\,{1 \over \pars{2\ic - 2}\pars{4\ic}} + {1 \over 8}\,\pi\ic} = \bbx{\ds{{1 \over 8}\,\pi}}
\end{align}

> $\mc{C}$ 'closes' the integration in the upper complex plane with and additional indent around $\ds{z = 2}$. There is a  simple pole, inside $\ds{\,\mc{C}}$, at $\ds{z = 2\ic}$.